Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore - "Cannot resolve symbol 'HasColumnType'"

Note: i could not use the code button for whatever reason, sry.

We currently have installed the following packages:
(.NETStandard 2.0) [old project, but currently we need to stay at this]

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" version="3.1.0"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions" version="3.1.0"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers" version="3.1.0"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" version="3.1.0"
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" version="3.1.0"

WebApiConfig.cs:
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) 
{

    // Web API configuration and services            
    config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
        new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

    // Web API routes config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute( name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate:
    "api/{controller}/{id}", defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional} );

    //ODataConfiguration config.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "odata route", routePrefix: "odata", model: GetEdmModel() );

}

private static IEdmModel GetEdmModel() 
{ 
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(); 
    builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();        
    builder.EntitySet<Domain>("DomainData"); //THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK -->  "Cannot resolve symbol 'HasColumnType'"
    builder.EntityType<Domain>().Property(x=>x.CreateDate).HasColumnType("datetime");
    return builder.GetEdmModel(); 
}

I have read that in order to use ".HasColumnType()", we need to have installed "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational".
We already have installed it, i also tried to remove all "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore*"-Packages and reinstall them, without any luck.
What may be the issue here??
Reason:
Whenever we try to use LINQ with a datetime filter like so:
var datetimetest = new DateTime(2024, 04, 16); 

var testquery = 
    from p in _context.Domain 
    where p.CreateDate <= datetimetest 
    select p;

we get an error:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

So i am not even sure if HasColumnType would fix that...

ODataConventionModelBuilder has nothing to EF, you should use HasColumnType in DbContext's OnModelCreating

It turns out the definition has to be made inside of "OnModelCreating" like that:
protected override void OnModelCreating([NotNull] ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  
  foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
  {
    foreach (IMutableProperty property in entityType.GetProperties().Where<IMutableProperty>((Func<IMutableProperty, bool>) (p => p.ClrType == typeof (DateTime) || p.ClrType == typeof (DateTime?))))
      property.SetColumnType("datetime");
  }
}

}
